# UITextView’s inputAccessoryView does not show up, if text predictions are turned off from keyboard settings in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, inputaccessoryview

I am developing a chat app where a text view is placed in Viewcontroller just like Whatsapp.
TextView moves above, along with keyboard exactly like whatsapp.

I need to show a toolbar containing some buttons,   in between keyboard and textview.
It is done by creating a toolbar and assigning it to INPUTACCESSORYVIEW of UITEXTVIEW.
It works perfectly unless user changes device settings as following.

**Settings —> General —> Keyboard —> predictive (Turned off).**

**After changing keyboard settings as above. An empty space appears in place of inputAccessoryView.**

I could not find anything similar to this problem.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Often while developing an app, We ran into an issues where the iPhone
>   keyboard slide up and cover the UITextField/UITextView.
>   IQKeyboardManager allows you to prevent issues of the keyboard sliding
>   up and cover UITextField/UITextView without needing you to enter any
>   code and no additional setup required. To use IQKeyboardManager you
>   simply need to add source files to your project.

So I recommend you to use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Comment: Thanks Ved for your suggestion. I Added this to my project but no luck.

Comment: Not Possible. Please make sure you have implemented it properly, @ArslanSaleem

Comment: I am developing app in Objective-C. I added pod to my project and installed according to instruction given in link.

Comment: After installation of pod, I ran my code, but problem is still same. Then i added following line of code in didFinishLaunch of  appDelegate.

[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].enable = YES;.

But Still problem is there.

Comment: For Objective - C, Just drag and drop IQKeyboardManager directory from demo project to your project. That's it.

Comment: I uninstalled pod of IQKeyboardManager. Then downloaded demo project and dropped IQKeyboard directory to my Project. Then I ran my code. But results are same. I am using many third parties in my code. Perhaps it is conflicting with some third party.

Comment: @ArslanSaleem can you please be sure top layout guide constraint or bottom layout constraint isn't directly or indirectly affecting the textField position? Because it's special case and we have other workarounds for this.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi, issue with my code was a third party, which I used to add rich text in textView. This third party was changing y position of accessoryView differently for different screen sizes. Removing these lines of code from that third party resolved my problem.Still i found,  Ved's answer as useful in managing accessoryView issues.